# Subtyping in Scala

Tags: scala, class, subtyping

I created a class that extends to Counter and it keeps track of the additions and subtractions. im trying to call xs and then return the sum of times that the number goes up or down that were called on instance by xs, Its compiling but its failing.

```
class Counter {
    private var n = 0
    def increment () = { n = n + 1 }
    def decrement () = { n = n - 1 }
    def get () : Int = n
}

def x (xs : Counter => Unit) : Int = {
    class foo extends Counter {
        var count = 0
        def incrementAndGet = {count += 1; count}
        def decrementAndGet = {count -= 1; count}
    }

    val counter1 = new foo
    xs(counter1)
    counter1.incrementAndGet
    counter1.decrementAndGet
}
```

Thanks everyone, I was actually able to pass it. I needed to create another variable that can keep track of my increments and decrements and then inside the def inc and def dec, i would add in to either add or subtract from count :)

Comment: How is Counter defined; what do you mean by 'failing', what would you expect the code to do,...? Please describe your problem in detail.

Comment: By my tests your code works fine. I guess it doesn't work the way you want but you haven't described what you want so it's hard to say. In particular, the statement `xs(counter1)` seems to be quite pointless.

Comment: There are many things wrong (or at least weird) with this code. What's the point of Counter attributes (`n`, `increment()`, `decrement()` and `get()`)? They are not used anywhere. Is there some missing code that uses this? Furthermore, what exactly is "total number of times that number goes up or down"? Should increment followed by decrement result in 2 or 0? Can you show how do you invoke `x`? What are you passing as `xs`? What's the point of invoking it? If you state your original problem without referring to your implementation, perhaps we can guide you to a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you have a look at the Java design patterns & best practices  first. Your foo class does not really extend counter since it does not shadow or override anything. Moreover you should use  a singleton (object counter...) to keep track of your additions & substractions. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually able to pass it. I needed to create another variable that can keep track of my increments and decrements and then inside the def inc and def dec, i would add in to either add or subtract from count :)